# mca or various ca (multivariate analysis)

Tags: r, statistics, ca

I will make an analysis about some information about my company.

I thought of making a **ca** to represent the association between two variables. I have 3 variables: Category, Tag, Valoration. My idea is to make 2 analyses, one to view the association between Category - Valorarion and a second analysis between Tag - Valoration.

But I think that this representation is possible with a `mca`.

What do you recommend to me?

Thank You

Comment: Are they all categorical variables? Are you referring to classification analysis or component analysis, both?

Comment: All variables are categorical. I will like to know the relations between categories of variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all variables are categorical, you can use multiple classification analysis to gain an understanding of the associations between the variables. There was a good article on the topic from the European Consortium for Politics back in 2k7 but I can't find it on my drive, I'm sure google will have it somewhere. I can't "see" your data so I can't say with any certainty that MCA will be better than regression or GLM but the article I'm referring to has a discussion on this topic specifically to do with MCA vs. GLM vs. Regression.

Alternatively, you could use pearson product-moment correlations to identify the   coefficients. Close to 1 = positive linear relationship, close to -1 = negative linear relationship, close to 0 = no linear relationship.

Comment: Found it: http://www.essex.ac.uk/ecpr/events/generalconference/pisa/papers/PP1468.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Various classification or association rule mining algorithms could be of much help too. You could check the [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~ml/weka/) toolbench for machine learning and data mining.

Comment: Hi.

Rapidminer I like more than Weka to work data mining projects.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I came across [VGAM package](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v32/i10/paper) for categorical data analysis. You could check this too